# Android: How can I resize an image to be automatically fitted with the View

Tags: android, matrix, android-imageview, imageswitcher

I have png floor map images. I am using the below code to set the default image size to fit with the view.

imageView is the view inside my ImageSwitcher:

```
imageView.setImageMatrix(createDefaultMatrix());

private Matrix createDefaultMatrix() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setValues(new float[]{1.136f, 0.0f, -17.204117f,0.0f, 1.136f, 66.24078f,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f});
    matrix.postScale(1.1085271f, 1.1085271f, 198.08646f, 304.4192f);
    return matrix;
}
```

If you have notice, I am using fix values just to fit the image with the view.

Any guidance on how to do it automatically fitted against its View is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you scale images? try CENTER_INSIDE

Comment: I am using MATRIX for zooming and dragging. (1) Is it possible to use CENTER_INSIDE while using MATRIX? (2) or may use CENTER_INSIDE for initial display then set it to MATRIX.. is it possible?